# Opening different activities with push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

There are 4 activities in my app, that can be opened from push notification. I am sending click_action = activity name form payload and I have set activity names in the manifest file. But when I send a push notification, only one activity is opening for all click_action mentions.

```
<activity
        android:name=".notification_1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="notification_1" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".notification_2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="notification_2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"     />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I want to open notification_2 when i send click_action = notification_2
and same with notification_1.

My notification class looks like this

```
NotificationMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String clickAction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

    Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 250, 250, 250, 250, 250});
    notificationBuilder.setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(1,notificationBuilder.build());

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

}
}
```

Comment: please post your notification class where you are setting the notification alert

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari I have edited my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can manually check the click action string and change your intent.

Example

```
    if(clickAction.equals("notification_1"){ 
        intent = new Intent(this,notification1.class);
     }
    else if(clickAction.equals("notification_2")
    {
        intent = new Intent(this,notification2.class);
    }
    else .........
```

2) You can send a custom data payload which you can capture in remoteMessage.getData() HashMap and do a if else check to create different intent.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-with-console#about_message_fields_in_the_notifications_composer

> data  Custom data Key/value pairs that you define. These are delivered as a data payload for the app to handle.